# Rails Admin (mongodb) : How can you edit an embedded document via rails admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, rails-admin

How to edit an embedded document via rails admin?
[image]

This is my example i have one Home model(for content)  and i have a Translation model. 
this is my home document:

```
[{
  "_id": "home",
  "title": {
      "_id":"home_title"
  },
  "subtitle": {
      "_id":"home_subtitle"
  }
}]
```

and my translation document:

[{
  "_id": "home_title",
  "en":"title",
  "pt":"titulo"
  },
  {
  "_id": "home_subtitle",
  "en":"subtitle",
  "pt":"subtitulo"
  }
]

Home has embedded translation.

in **home.rb**:

```
class Home
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title
  field :subtitle
  embeds_one :title, as: :translatable, class_name: 'Translation'
  embeds_one :subtitle, as: :translatable, class_name: 'Translation'
end
```

in translation.rb:

```
class Translation

  include Mongoid::Document
  attr_accessor :_id
  embedded_in :translatable

  field :pt
  field :en

end
```

how can you edit an embedded document via rails admin? Supposing is a 1:1 relantionship.